# Ubuntu 23.10 tiling assistant stops working with Alt as hotkey for moving the window

Tags: extension, tiling, 23.10

In Ubuntu 23.10, changing the window-move mouse button modifier from <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> with e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Alt>'
```

and then trying to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging the window from its center (or anything but the title bar), to edge/corner, does not perform tiling.

It would appear the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant does not use same value as the hotkey.

Reverting the changes with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Super>'
```

makes the tiling work with <kbd>Super</kbd> again.

**Fixes I've tried:**

I installed `gnome-shell-extension-manager` and had a look at the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant settings, but couldn't find one related to this.

---

EDIT: This might be a bug since as per [lines 50..55 of the source](https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant/blob/main/tiling-assistant%40leleat-on-github/src/extension/moveHandler.js#L50), or in

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com/src/extension/moveHandler.js
```

It would seem using <kbd>Alt</kbd> is intended to be handled:

```
const altAsMod = wmPrefs.get_string('mouse-button-modifier') === '<Alt>';
if (altAsMod) {
    for (const s of [Settings.ADAPTIVE_TILING_MOD, Settings.FAVORITE_LAYOUT_MOD]) {
        const mod = Settings.getInt(s);
        if (mod === 1) // 1 -> Alt; see settings ui
            Settings.setInt(s, 3); // 3 -> Super; see settings ui
```